# What is the best way to figure out if an RDD had to be recomputed or not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching

I have suspected that some of the cache statements in my Spark Application were unnecessary, so I have removed several of the cache statements. Is there a way to verify on subsequent runs whether or not certain RDDs had to be recomputed or not by Spark?

EDIT

Can this only be accomplished with log statements?

It would seem that you would end up with a ton of log statements because they would be output for each executor.